# How to enable the page number counter but don't display it in the titlepage in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I have observed some books and find that these books start the page number counter in the titlepage (some even do this from the cover) but don't display the page number in the titlepage, also the verso of it. The structure of the document is as follows:

```
% we assume that page numbers are doublesided.
\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\startstandardmakeup
... % titlepage
\stopstandardmakeup
\stopfrontmatter
\stoptext
```

how to do this in ConTeXt?

Comment: Place `\setcounter[userpage][2]` after `\stopstandardmakeup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start]
```

See [ConTeXt wiki - setupmakeup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup). Or you can move the `\startfrontmatter` after `\stopstandardmakeup` and use

```
\startsectionblockenvironment [frontpart]
  \setcounter [userpage] [2]
\stopsectionblockenvironment
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment `\setupmakeup` has the disadvantage of creating a new page at `\stopmakeup`, apart from vertically centering its contents. 
If this default makeup formatting is not desired, a conditional `\setupheadertexts` may offer a more versatile solution:

```
\setupheadertexts[\doifnot\pagenumber1{Page \currentpage}]
```

Comment: You can change both behavior (not create a new page  or not vertically center the content).